# python - Comparing two list of dictionaries by one key

Tags: python, list, dictionary, comparison

I have two list of dictionaries like this:

```
listOne = [{'A':'a','B':'b','C':'c'},{'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'},{'A':'aaa','B':'bbb','C':'ccc'}]
listTwo = [{'A':'a','B':'b'},{'A':'aa','B':'bb'},{'A':'aaa','B':'bbb'},{'A':'aaaa','B':'bbbb'}]
```

what I want to do is to compare listOne and listTwo by their 'A' key and if there isn't the dictionary with 'A' key in both list, the script prints it.

Is it possible?

Thanks ;

EDIT:

Ok, I'm sorry, the question was unclear, so:

I have two different-sized list of dictionaries, the dictionaries in listTwo have the same keys and same values of some of the dictionaries in listOne, but they have one more key.

What I need to do is to print the dictionaries that are not in listTwo.

I cannot do:

```
for i in listOne:
    if i not in listTwo:
        print(i)
```

because of course in listTwo the dictionaries have one more element, so I don't know how to compare only two keys values of these dictionaries...

I want to do something like:

```
for i in listOne:
    if i['A'] not in listTwo.elementsKey['A']:
        print(i)
```

but I don't figure it out how to do that... Any possibilities?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you want to check whether each `list` contains at least one dictionary that contains a key of `'A'`?

Comment: print the dictionaries which 'A' value is not in both list

Comment: What would be your expected result in this case?

Comment: {'A':'aaaa','B':'bbbb'}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i figured it out how to solve it (in a very, very ugly way):

```
listOne = [{'A':'a','B':'b','C':'c'},{'A':'aa','B':'bb','C':'cc'},{'A':'aaa','B':'bbb','C':'ccc'}]
listTwo = [{'A':'a','B':'b'},{'A':'aa','B':'bb'},{'A':'aaa','B':'bbb'},{'A':'aaaa','B':'bbbb'}]

listValues = []

for i in listOne:
    listValues.append(i['A'])
for i in listTwo:
    if i['A'] not in listValues:
        print(i)
```

Thanks for your support :)

Comment: I have the same question with two keys instead of one.  Your answer is useful for this; thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
def checkList(lst):
    for item in lst:
        if "A" not in item.keys():
            print item
checkList(listOne)
checkList(listTwo)
```

Answer (score -2):

Yes, it is possible.

No, SO is not a place where people write code for you.

But to be nice, (and lacking ability to comment this instead), try something like:

```
 from itertools import chain
 keysA = set(chain.from_iterable([d.keys() for d in listOne]))
 keysB = set(chain.from_iterable([d.keys() for d in listTwo]))
 if 'A' not in keysA and 'A' not in keysB:
      print "'A' not in both lists"
 else:
      doyourcomparehere
```

Comment: I need to compare the values of the two set, sorry my question was unclear.